# Given a limited amount of time and an unlimited access to resources. Do the majority of people tend to solve a problem the "quick and dirty" way?

Tags: problem-solving

In my field of work (Manufacturing), I've noticed this behavior quite often.
It doesn't matter how much resources they have, if they are under pressure, most people will try to solve a specific problem the fastest way possible, without taking the time to look for better alternatives.

While it might not apply to everyone, I've seen this pattern often enough to wonder if there's some studies around this particular subject ?

Any documents that could help me understand would be really appreciated !

Comment: Similar to [Research on aversion to cognitive effort?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/10516/7001)

Comment: You probably notice it more due to your experience. In manufacturing work, process oriented, step-by-step reasoning is very important, and shortcuts could have a really bad outcome. But in other areas maybe not so much. You should add some examples of the "quick and dirty" shortcuts you are referring to. I would guess it's risk vs. benefit.